# Why getting the FB profile picture using graph API needs access token?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I want to show the profile picture using the `graph api` using the following link fpor example :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?redirect=0&height=200&type=normal&width=200
```

I get the response :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

Where in the  [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/) they say

> Because profile pictures are always public on Facebook, this call does
>   not require any access token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `me` in the URI is just a placeholder, you need to put an actual Facebook `user-id` in, like the title (`/{user-id}/picture`) of your linked page suggests.

For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/snoopdogg/picture?redirect=0&height=200&type=normal&width=200
```

...returns the following:

```
{
   "data": {
      "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/c11.0.433.433/s200x200/598452_10151897536239807_882122819_n.jpg",
      "width": 200,
      "height": 200,
      "is_silhouette": false
   }
}
```

Comment: Previously I can remember that 'me' was working for the current user

Comment: @Adham Ah interesting. And isn't it a bug anyways for the API to return your error for any `user-id` (including invalid ones)?